# search button not working after i send search data and create dynamic html using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

when user clicks on search button , i get input value and then through axios i send a get request with search data , everything works fine but when i query databse and then dynamically create data from mongoose data , the page reloads without showing that data on page

```
let dynamicBuild = (res) => {
  if (getDiv) {
    return (
      res.data
        .map((element) => {
          return `<div class="innercard"> <img src="/adminImages/${element._id}/${element.PizzaImage}"  width="300px" height="200px" > 
                
<h4 class="h4"><b>${element.pizzaCategory}</b></h4>

<h4 class="h4"><b>$ ${element.pizzaPrice}</b></h4>

<button type="button"   onclick="location.href='/admin/editPizzas/<%=element._id%>'" class="btn btn-success">BuY Now </button>


  </div>`;
        })
        .join('') + `</div>`
    );
  }
};


let getSearchButton = document.getElementsByClassName(
  'btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 bg-light'
);

if (getSearchButton) {
  getSearchButton[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   
    let getSearch = document.getElementById('sr').value;

    searchData = {
      search: getSearch,
    };
    sendSearchQuery(searchData);
  });
}

let sendSearchQuery = (searchData) => {
  axios.get(`/home/search/${searchData.search}`).then((res) => {
    let markup = dynamicBuild(res);

    getDiv[0].innerHTML = markup;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, just check how you are getting the response (i.e structure of the 'res' array).

I think it should be fetched as 'res.data' (i.e call as dynamicBuild(res.data)).

Comment: im getting the res.data  by passing res to dynamic build and then accessing res.data in dynamic build function ...